# Press zero any number of times in edit text, but it should be visible to user in only 1 digit like Calculator

Tags: android, android-edittext, calculator

I have an edit text to fill amount. So, I added text watcher, but I don't want user to "0000000..." if user will continuously press "0000..." instead it should show only one time '0' like Calculator

How can I do that?

```
private void setAmount() {
    etAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() == 1) {
                if (s.toString().equals("0")) {
                    etAmount.setText("0");
                }
            }

            //Not working
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });
}
```

I think, my logic is also wrong, because when I enter single input and check `s.length`, and after `et.setText("0")`, it will go to infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    etAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String text = s.toString();
            if (text.length() == 2 && text.charAt(0) == '0') {
                etAmount.setText(text.substring(1));
                etAmount.setSelection(1);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
etAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.length() == 2) {
            if (s.toString().startsWith("00")) {
                etAmount.setText("0");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sry! Not working, it is not even input any number, please try something else